# How can I see port forwarding that I have set up?

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm using macOS and I'd like to know a command to see the status of my port forwarding command:

`sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/xxx.pem -N -f -L 443:127.0.0.1:8888 ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxx-x.compute.amazonaws.com`

What command can I use to see that this port forwarding is set up?

Comment: `wget http://127.0.0.1:443/ -O /dev/null`

Comment: @IporSircer please post as an answer not a comment. Thank you.